# the meaning of a coding statement i |= bit << bit

Tags: loops, operators

I am pursuing an online course somewhat related to java and there i have to submit answers of the homework given by them every week.Recently i have got a homework in which there was a loop :-

```
    private static String createAnswer() {
    int i = 0;
    for (int bit = 0; bit < 16; bit++) {
        i |= bit << bit;
    }
    return Integer.toString(i);
}
```

I would be really thankful if someone could explain me the meaning of this code. I have tried to google it but did not found any relevant answer.

Comment: why don't you debug it and see what happens step by step? if you don't know how to debug then insert print statements and find out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> `i |= bit << bit;`

These are [bitwise operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C).

`bit << bit` does a [left bitshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Left_shift_.3C.3C), moving the bits to the left `bit` times.

The `|=` or [bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_OR_.22.7C.22) and assign operator combines the bits of the result of the bitshift and `i` and assigns it to `i`.